# Java String regular expression on string array to capture nested data

Tags: java, regex, string

```
[
Dobj(id=null, dmetaD=DmetaD(id=2068, embedded=true, size=123, comment=raghu, name=string, type=pdf)),dcont=DConD(data=abc)),
Dobj(id=null, dmetaD=DmetaD(id=2069, embedded=true, size=123, comment=raghu, name=string, type=pdf)),dcont=DConD(data=abc))
]
```

As you can see in the above object array i want to split and retrieve all the objects starting with the name **DmetaD** and **DConD** as string .

example:

```
String x=DmetaD(id=2068, embedded=true, size=123, comment=raghu, name=string, type=pdf))

String y=DConD(data=abc)
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the source of this data?  Wouldn't it be easier to extract data from the original Java objects themselves?

Comment: This is transported as a string from producer to subscriber in queue which is basically a list converted to string.

Comment: Well I would vote for converting back into a list on the other end and then using normal Java to extract the information you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pattern & Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with this regex [`(DmetaD\\(.*?\\)|DConD\\(.*?\\))`](https://regex101.com/r/RG4PXn/1) for example If you are using Java 9+ :

```
String input = "...";
String regex = "(DmetaD\\(.*?\\)|DConD\\(.*?\\))";
List<String> result = Pattern.compile(regex)
        .matcher(input)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output

```
DmetaD(id=2068, embedded=true, size=123, comment=raghu, name=string, type=pdf)
DConD(data=abc)
DmetaD(id=2069, embedded=true, size=123, comment=raghu, name=string, type=pdf)
DConD(data=abc)
```

Before Java 9 you can use :

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group());
}
```

---

Details about the regex `(DmetaD\(.*?\)|DConD\(.*?\))`

- `DmetaD\(.*?\)` a matches which start with `DmetaD` followed by any thing between parenthesis.
- `|` or
- `DConD\(.*?\)` a matches which start with `DConD` followed by any thing between parenthesis.

Comment: Just getting a compilation error The method results() is undefined for the type Matcher

Comment: It seems you are not using Java 9+ try the second solution @Prash

Comment: ,please take a look at this json and can you please help me to get dmetaD and dCont.

https://github.com/javayp/stream-zipkin/blob/master/client-appd.json

Comment: @Prash I strongly suggest to use a JSon parser instead of regex, there are many ways to parse a JSon